# Why does optionsFromCapabilities exist only on WMTS?

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-6

I'd like to use WMS capabilities document to get right options for WMS layer without further parsing. However, I see it can be only done for WMTS using https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_source_WMTS.html#.optionsFromCapabilities (it does not exist on WMS format).

Why is that?

Comment: WMTS can be much more complicated to set up as it often uses a custom tile grid.  WMTS optionsFromCapabilities always needs configuration options, which is similar to the params of a WMS source.  WMTS optionsFromCapabilities will construct the tilegrid, which is not needed for WMS (even with TileWMS using a default grid is sufficient).